# Showing image before the thread starts C#

Tags: c#

I have a program that has a ability to generate lot's of Textfiles and I want to put a loading animation on my form when the program is performing the thread of Generating textfile. That's why I decided to download a .gif loading image in google and show it before the program execute the command. But it is not showing. Can you help with this problem. It's just minimal but I can't resolve it. Thank you in advance

```
private void btn_Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pic_Loading.Visible = true;
        if ((dt_To.Value - dt_From.Value).TotalDays >= 0)
        {
            for (var day = dt_From.Value; day <= dt_To.Value; day = day.AddDays(1))
            {
                string path = txt_path.Text + @"\" + day.ToString("yyyy");
                BLL.CreateFolder.CreateNewFolder(path);
                if (chk_txtFile.Checked == true)
                {
                    BLL.InsertData.InsertDailySales(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, day.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), txt_texttenant.Text, txt_StoreKey.Text, "p_Aya_insert_daily");
                    BLL.InsertData.InsertDailySales(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, day.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), txt_texttenant.Text, txt_StoreKey.Text, "p_AYA_insert_hourly_First");
                    BLL.InsertData.InsertDailySales(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, day.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), txt_texttenant.Text, txt_StoreKey.Text, "p_AYA_insert_hourly_Sec");

                    BLL.PopulateData.LoadToDatagrid(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, "Select * from DAILY", dg_DailySales);
                    BLL.PopulateData.LoadToDatagrid(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, "Select * from HOURLY", dg_Hourly);

                    BLL.ExportData.ExportDaiySales(dg_DailySales, path + @"\" + txt_textContract.Text + day.ToString("MMdd"));
                    BLL.ExportData.ExportHourlySales(dg_Hourly, path + @"\" + txt_textContract.Text + day.ToString("MMdd"));
                }

                if (chk_DBF.Checked == true)
                {
                    BLL.InsertData.InsertDailySales(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, day.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), txt_DBFTenantName.Text, txt_StoreKey.Text, "p_AYA_insertintodailydbf");
                    BLL.PopulateData.LoadToDatagrid(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, "Select * from DailyDBF", dg_DBFDaily);

                    BLL.InsertData.InsertDailySales(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, day.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), txt_DBFTenantName.Text, txt_StoreKey.Text, "p_AYA_InsertHourly_DBF1");
                    BLL.InsertData.InsertDailySales(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, day.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"), txt_DBFTenantName.Text, txt_StoreKey.Text, "p_AYA_InsertHourly_DBF2");
                    BLL.PopulateData.LoadToDatagrid(txt_Server.Text, cbo_Databasename.Text, txt_Uname.Text, txt_Password.Text, "Select * from HourlyDBF", dg_DBFHourly);

                    string Fields = "TRANDATE D, OLDGT N(15,2), NEWGT N(15,2), DLYSALE N(15,2), TOTDISC N(15,2), TOTREF N(15,2), TOTCAN N(15,2), VAT N(15,2), TENTNAME C(50), BEGINV I, " +
                                    " ENDINV N(11), BEGOR N(11), ENDOR N(11), TRANCNT N(11), LOCALTX N(15,2), SERVCHARGE N(15,2), NOTAXSALE N(15,2), RAWGROSS N(15,2), DLYLOCTAX N(15,2), OTHERS  N(11), TERMNUM C(50)";
                    BLL.CreateDBF.CreateDBFile(path, txt_DBFTenantCode.Text + day.ToString("MMdd"), Fields);

                    string Hourly = "TRANDATE D, HOUR C(50), SALES N(15,2), TRANCNT N(11), TENTNAME C(50), TERMNUM C(50)";
                    BLL.CreateDBF.CreateDBFile(path, txt_DBFTenantCode.Text + day.ToString("MMdd") + "H", Hourly);

                    BLL.InsertToDBF.InsertData(path, dg_DBFDaily, txt_DBFTenantCode.Text + day.ToString("MMdd"));
                    BLL.InsertToDBF.Hourly(path, dg_DBFHourly, txt_DBFTenantCode.Text + day.ToString("MMdd") + "H");
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            pic_Loading.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Date");
        }
    }
```

Comment: After `pic_Loading.Visible = true` you have to give a chance for your form to display it. `Application.DoEvents()` (right after that line) is one way, but there are better ways of course.

Comment: Try to put your code in a [BackGroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Put the long running code inside [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), now btn_Generate_Click should only contain pic_Loading.Visible = true and RunWorkerAsync(), move the MessageBox and hiding pic_Loading on BackgroundWorker Complete

Comment: To whose who suggest `BackgroundWorker` (or thread, or task), that code contains much of GUI controls access, if you say that mention `Invoke` please as well.

Comment: What do you mean about GUI Controls Sir?

Comment: [Cross thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx) operation on GUI controls require them

Comment: By the way I use the Application.Event but the Animation of the .gif didn't run. it is like the form is locked when the thread is executing the command of generating textfiles.

Comment: How to use the backgroudworker? Is it better if I use? or There is no way to do my desired animation on my form.

Comment: All the GUI code I see is just reading TextBox values. You can read them into variables before calling to the BackgroundWorker, no need to `Invoke` for what i see @Sinatr

Comment: Novice, read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx). There is a pretty self explanatory sample of how to use a BackgroundWorker there

Comment: @Pikoh the PopulateData.LoadToDatagrid probably edit the datagrid

Comment: You are right @Martheen, i missed that one :)

Comment: I'm sorry. those are functions.

Answer (score 0):

I Finally did it. I used BackgroudWorker. Thank you for your help guys.